# Why do I see a large number of connections in V$SESSION for a period of time?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We are tuning up a server where clients can create queries and send them to Oracle. This server can create a pool and have connections on standby. The number of standby connections is something we can control and that is what we are trying to tune up. So, while we are tuning up this minimal number of connection on standby we were checking the V$SESSION table to see the connections standing by and when they were active. At that moment of being active is when we started to see this number of "connections" grow up to 70 or 80 at a time while the query was executing. My guess is that these are not connections per se. Looks like the places where it is reading the data from?? I am not sure and that is why I'd like to know. What are those? They only show when the query executes. Here is the query I am using to check in oracle what my connections are doing:

```
select TO_CHAR(s.prev_exec_start, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "LAST_RAN", s.*
from V$SESSION s
where username = 'MY_USER_NAME';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could show some of the output from your query, but it is very possible that what you are seeing are parallel execution threads for some of the queries. These will spawn automatically to handle the parallel processing requirements and generally have process names like 'P000', 'P001', etc.

The level of parallelism for a query can be defined as part of the related object properties, or within query hints. Short making changes at the system level to parallel processing behavior (see [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/parameters-parallel-exec.html#GUID-7ED3242C-D2FF-4279-AF8A-C7CFB7ED5F2A)), or disabling parallel processing entirely for these sessions - which might completely kill query performance - there isn't much you can do.

A logon trigger to disable parallel execution might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APP_SCHEMA_LOGON_TRG
AFTER LOGON ON APP_USER.SCHEMA
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL QUERY';
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you are absolutely right. I checked an all those processes are marked with a P031, P012, etc. That specific database is an exadata database and all queries run in parallel. Thank you again!